# Why is the order of types in Python 2 fixed, and an unorderable TypeError in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**Question 1**: Why is this order of types in Python 2 fixed?

```
object > type > tuple > (bytes or str) > frozenset > set > dict \
       > long > list > int > float > complex > bytearray > None

True
```

Is this because of their `id()` in their lifetime?

```
for t in types:
    print repr(t), id(t)

<type 'object'> 4439116416
<type 'type'> 4439115752
<type 'tuple'> 4439113712
<type 'str'> 4439103312
<type 'frozenset'> 4439096880
<type 'set'> 4439095648
<type 'dict'> 4439083728
<type 'long'> 4439081736
<type 'list'> 4439076128
<type 'int'> 4439074040
<type 'float'> 4439065096
<type 'complex'> 4439029656
<type 'bytearray'> 4439016144
None 4439091192
```

Or, because of Python builtin import time? Same result in another shell:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan 29 2015, 06:27:40)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> object > type > tuple > (bytes or str) > frozenset > set > dict > long > list > int > float > complex > bytearray > None
True
```

However tested it in Python 3, it will be a `TypeError`:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Feb 25 2015, 21:28:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> object > type > tuple > (bytes or str) > frozenset > set > dict > long > list > int > float > complex > bytearray > None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: type() > type()
```

**Question 2**: why is this a `TypeError` in Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because that's how the developers of Python decided to do it. That order is hard-coded in the interpreter (for CPython at least; other implementations may do it differently). The idea was to have a list containing various data types sort in a consistent order.
2. Because the developers of Python decided they'd made a mistake with the Python 2.x behavior and decided that "explicit is better than implicit". Now you must provide a `key` function when sorting lists containing items of different types to make sure you get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks and that makes sense. But then if I create 2 empty classes let say `class A` and `class B`, `B > A == True`, is that internally it's comparing their `id()`? since both their types will be `<class 'type'>` and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: "That order is hard-coded in the interpreter" - you sure about that? [`type_richcompare`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/feb0717c1004/Objects/typeobject.c#l632) seems to compare addresses.

Comment: I think in that case the addresses are in fact compared, at least in Python 2.x It doesn't really make sense to compare two classes using an inequality, though, so the use cases in which this would even come up must be mighty unusual. I should also mention, this is how Python operates by default; you can override any of it. in the case of a class, you can override comparison using a metaclass.

Comment: By "that order is hard-coded in the interpreter" I mean the orders of different types when you compare them.

Comment: Sorry about being late to accept your answer. I have gone through the source code which @user2357112 commented. Indeed the ordering of other objects is compared by memory address like I suspected. Anyhow the reasons behind as you explained, are very clear and especially answer (2) is just brilliant as I need to adopt Python3 and migrate a project to it. Thanks again pal :-)