# Unorderable types: str() > float () in when filtering generator expression

Tags: python, generator

My code was working perfectly all the time and suddenly this error appears:

```
unorderable types: str() > float()
```

[image]

I extract the orderbook via API and than want to get all orders with a higher amount than 1.

```
filtermaxxamount = (x for x in dic if x['max_amount'] > 1)
```

This appears to be a "generator" class.
Then I want to extract the highest price from `filtermaxxamount` with:

```
highestprice = ((max((x for x in filtermaxxamount if x['min_amount'] < 1), 
                     key=lambda x:x['price']))['price'])
```

After this I get the error mentioned above.
It all worked well before and I had no problems. The API was not changed I checked that on the website.

What kind of mistake do I have?
What is the problem? It must be a dictionary instead of a generator right?

Comment: Could you paste the full error stacktrace in your question? This will allow us to see which line exactly raises the error

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have switched from Python 2 to Python 3.

In *Python 2* all `type`s were orderable:

```
print(sorted( [1,"2",3,"None"]`))  
# Output: [1,3,'2','None']
```

In *Python 3* this is no longer the case:

```
print(sorted( [1,"2",3,"None"]`))  
# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' 

# workaround for sorting: use an explicit key function
print(sorted( [1,"2",3,"None"], key=lambda x: 999999999999 if isinstance(x,str) else x))
```

See [Why is the order of types in Python 2 fixed, and an unorderable TypeError in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618165/why-is-the-order-of-types-in-python-2-fixed-and-an-unorderable-typeerror-in-pyt)

---

**To fix your problem:** (and the reason I answered in addition to dupe suggesting)

Filter your elements to those that have a float value and non a string:

```
l = [ {'max_amount' : 33.0}, {'max_amount' : -33.0}, {'max_amount' : 12.6},
      {'max_amount' : "None"}, {'max_amount' : "34"}]

try:
    # only look at those that are floats (seperated for clarity)
    filter_float = (x for x in l if isinstance(x['max_amount'],float))

    # from those filter the > 1 ones
    filtermaxxamount = (x for x in filter_float if x['max_amount'] > 1)

    # creates an error:
    # filtermaxxamount = (x for x in l if x['max_amount'] > 1)
    print(*filtermaxxamount) 
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)  # never reached unless you uncomment # filtermaxxamount = (x for x in l ...
```

Output:

```
{'max_amount': 33.0} {'max_amount': 12.6}
```

Comment: An interesting point! As one who started with Python 3.x, I didn't really know about this kind of behavior. Seems like those days Python was somewhat more similar to JavaScript =)

Comment: thanks for your help Patrick . The issue is that I am using python 3.x all the time and the code work without any problems. I made no changes, I guess it is from the API provider they changed something but didn't mention...... It worked for almost 2 years!! and suddenly it stops working how is that possible ;( . I want to solve this problem, but I can not find the mistake...... Will keep trying....